# Puzzeling error "File does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony-2.3, symfony-3.2

I have checked file exists, but showing error for some image file, not all.

```
$photo = $request->request->get('photo');
$obj = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($photo); // getting error from this line.
```

Comment: Does symfony have read access to the file?

Comment: yes, its not working for some image files.

Comment: i want to get image file info from image path. please help.

Comment: Did you figure out why it was happening? I have the same problem with a file in S3. When I visit the link in the error I can see it. When it is in the new object, i get the error.